# iPhone keyboard on UiPopOverController (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard

i would to know if there is a way to show(call) an iphone-uikeybord-like inside a UIPopOverController. I've an ipad app with several functions, in one of these there is a button that show a popoover, inside the popover there are a uitableviewcontroller and a  search controller for search functions inside the table; search stuff is numeric only and i want show a keyboard(like numberpad in iphone) inside the popover instead show the maxi ipad keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that - but you'll have to build a custom keyboard.

I did exactly the same thing to create a numeric keypad after playing around trying to use a different UIControl for the text field input without much success.

My solution was specific to our app because we also wanted - and + keys to adjust the value without by tapping, but what I ended up doing was:

- extend UITextField
- add - and + buttons next to it
- add a transparent button on top of the numeric field
- trigger UIPopOverController when the transparent button was tapped
- the popover loaded a NumericKeypad with it's own view

Although I usually try to use IB as much as possible in this case all buttons and target assignments were done in code (for easy of calculating relative positions in code)

The creation of the keyboard itself is really easy - it's just a bunch of buttons. You can either build in IB or programmatically - quite simple either way.